# Using SelectorGadget and RVest pulling the underlying html, rather than the text I want to capture

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to pull a column of data from basketballreference.com, this one to be particular:

http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/ATL/2016.html

Using selectorGadget I am able to highlight the part of the page that I want and then it gives me the parameter to put int the html_nodes function. However, I am trying to pull the names of the players, but when I copied and pasted selectorGadget's output, it gives me the link that the name contains. I was wondering if anyone knew how to have it match the actual text, rather than the link that it contains. For example, the first name in the list is Kent Bazemore. I would like it to return Kent Bazemore, but instead it is capturing the underlying html:

```
{xml_node} 'a href="/players/b/bazemke01.html"'
```

If anyone has any advice on how to clean this up I would really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the nodes is just the first step. Extracting the text is a second method - in this case, `html_text()`.

I'd use an `xpath` expression to get the player names in this case:

```
library(rvest)

u <- "http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/ATL/2016.html"
u %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='roster']/tbody/tr/td[@data-stat='player']/a") %>%
  html_text()

[1] "Kent Bazemore"   "Tim Hardaway"    "Kirk Hinrich"    "Justin Holiday"  "Al Horford"     
[6] "Kris Humphries"  "Kyle Korver"     "Shelvin Mack"    "Paul Millsap"    "Mike Muscala"   
[11] "Lamar Patterson" "Dennis Schroder" "Mike Scott"      "Thabo Sefolosha" "Tiago Splitter" 
[16] "Edy Tavares"     "Jeff Teague"
```